# Rsync path with ()

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

can somone tell me how i get this line to work?

```
rsync -rtvz --delete --exclude-from exclude.txt --out-format="%M %o %n" -e "ssh -p 2323 -i /root/.ssh/server" Administrator@someserver.dynv6.net:'/cygdrive/C/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/Anfrage Eingang (AFE)/ '/volume2/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/Anfrage Eingang (AFE)/'
```

I got this error message -ash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

It is a synology DSM 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Administrator@someserver.dynv6.net:'/cygdrive/C/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/Anfrage Eingang (AFE)/' '/volume2

looks like you're missing a closing tick ' between (AFE)/ and /volume2

Also you may need to escape the parentheses \( \)

Comment: hmm Thanks now i got this

receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/C/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/Anfrage" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Administrator.SERVER/Eingang" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Administrator.SERVER/(AFE)" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 220 bytes  received 10 bytes  153.33 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1898) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Comment: Check the file paths to make sure they are correct. It's saying /cygdrive/etc doesn't exist.

Comment: If i do
`rsync -rtvz --delete --exclude-from exclude.txt --out-format="%M %o %n" -e "ssh -p 2323 -i /root/.ssh/server" Administrator@someserver.dynv6.net:'/cygdrive/C/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/' '/volume2/Nas/Public/Büro/Kunde/'`

its working and also syncronise a folder called "Anfrage Eingang (AFE)"

receiving incremental file list
2017/06/13-08:29:30 recv Anfrage Eingang (AFE)/
2017/04/12-09:19:00 recv Anfrage Eingang (AFE)/Müllabwurf.PDF

Comment: Ah, try escaping the space in 'Anfrage Eingang'

>'Anfrage\ Eingang\ \(AFE\)'

Comment: I did, its same result

Comment: Also same result, maybe its because something with remote cygwin rsync?

Answer (score 1):

This one did the Job :-)

If you need to transfer a filename that contains whitespace, you can either specify the --protect-args (-s) option, or you'll need to escape the whitespace in a way that the remote shell will understand. For instance:

So the final answer is if you want to avoid errors with spaces and brackets on local copy just use double quotes for vars like:

```
source="/root/new folder ()/"
dest="/root/some other folder ()"
rsync -rtvz --delte "$source" "$dest"
```

If you want to copy from a remote host then the --protect-args flag has to be set.

```
rsync -rtvz --delete --protect-args -e "ssh -p 22 -i /root/.ssh/somekey" root@someserver:"$source" "$dest"
```

or

```
rsync -rtvzs --delete -e "ssh -p 22 -i /root/.ssh/somekey" root@someserver:"$source" "$dest"
```

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete. Please only post an answer if it really solved your own problem, and include all the necessary commands.